# Exchange have disconnection Issue while using behind TMG 2010

Tags: exchange, outlook, internet, outlook-web-app, tmg

We have two branch office but not VPN (Data Circuit) between them. We are using Exchange facility from another branch but we are having disconnection / slow issue as already set TMG alerts. Outlook and OWA access issue time to time but internet is working proper during this period.

Note:

01) TMG 2010 Configured with Edge Firewall Topology and allow All outbound traffic to External.

02) Exchange have no issue when using without TMG  and even behind the Wireless router.

Can anyone help?